# Undefined variable in flag++

Tags: php, undefined

The program I'm working on is supposed to be records the events in calendar. But I am getting an undefined variable error in my php code. The errors are on line 79. I'm guessing the `$flag-1` is out of scope, but I'm not sure. Can anyone help me?

```
    $output.="<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'><tr class ='tit'><td colspan='2'> Total Events:".($flag-1)."</td></tr></table>";
    if($flag == 1)
    {
        $output.="<i><h2>No Events Found</h2></i>";
        $output.="<input type='button' value='back' onClick='searchBack()'>";
    }

    return $output;
}
else
{
    $output.="<a href='../templates/search.php'>Plz select your days</a>";
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: question title and code given have no relation at all

Comment: Where is $flag initialized?

Comment: which variable is undefined, `$flag` or `$output`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined $flag outside your function/statement? This is most likely the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined $output before?

Otherwise use

```
$output = "<table..."; 
instead of $output .= "<table...";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using **return** keyword. The code you have listed - is it a part of function?
If so, may be that **$flag** is out of your *function scope*?

In function case, if **$flag** is defined outside of function, try passing it as one of function arguments.

On the other side, you have **$output .=** 
If **$output** is not defined previously, you must use **$output =** or define it, some thing like **$output = '';**